# Run NN code multiple times in a single run and build average of the result

Tags: neural-network

Hello I want to ask how I can run my neural network many times in just a single run and build the average accuracy (and precision) of all runs?

Answer (score 0):

When training a neural network you have two parameters the training set: **The batch and epoch**. 
The batch is how many datapoint from you training set you want to pass together, usually the higher the greater is the stability but it goes without saying that it comes at more computational cost.

The epoch is the number of time you go through your entire dataset. Hence if you want to run N time your neural network on the same dataset you will have to choose an epoch equal to N.